# RewritePath doesn't change HttpContext.Current.Request

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an httpModule that allows me to have custom urls, but direct the url to a specified page with additional query string info.

Let's say I use context.RewritePath to rewrite "Custom/Path" to a "/Path.aspx?queryKey=value"

When I try to recieve the "queryKey" query parameter, it doesn't exist because the Request.Path is still "Custom/Path".

How do I get the Request.Path to be "/Path.aspx?queryKey=value" so that I can get query string info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "../Path.aspx?queryKey=value", if you need to go back one directory.

Also, you would probably want to add a false for the rebaseClientPath option.